# SPRESENSE ポート認識しない

Tags: arduino, spresense

SPRESENSがArduino IDE上のシリアルポートで認識しません。

以前までは認識していたのですが１、２週間後再接続してみたらツール→シリアルポートの欄が灰色になって選択できません。

SPRESENSE自体はパソコンに繋げると青く光るので認識していると思います。

解決につながる情報を頂ければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USBケーブルは確認しましたか？

USBケーブルの中には、電源供給だけを目的としたものがあり、データラインがないものがあります。そのようなケーブルを使うとPCがデバイスを認識できません。

またマイクロUSBコネクタは、接触が悪くなることもあるので、そのようなケースも考えられます。実際に、私のスマホは相性が悪いケーブルがあったりします。

いずれにしても、USBケーブルを一度確認したほうがよいかも知れませんね。

Comment: いろいろなUSBケーブルを試してみましたが結果は変わらずでした。

Comment: そうですか。以下の手順をもう一度確認してみてはいかがでしょう？ライブラリも最近バージョンアップされていますし。特にコントロールパネルで確認できるかどうかがポイントですね。

https://developer.sony.com/ja/develop/spresense/developer-tools/get-started-using-arduino-ide/set-up-the-arduino-ide

それでも問題が出るようでしたら、初期不良の可能性もあるので、販売店に問い合わせてみたほうがいいかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 2):

CP210x USB to serial driver for Windows 10

を再インストールしたらできました。

回答ありがとうございました！